# Create relationship/link between multiple table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a table `positions` in which I would like to create a relationship between multiple table rows. If the number of rows that need to be "linked" together is unknown, what makes the most sense with a separate table to link the ids?

Is it best to...

- Create a separate table `links` with many columns (ie: linked_id1 [...] linked_id[n]) where the linked_ids are the id of each row and the `links.id` column is the id of the link. The logic is that we can create more columns than we think we will need.

OR

- Create a separate table `links` with two columns, `id` and `linked_ids` where `linked_ids` is a comma separated array of the "linked" rows from `positions`.

OR

- Do the aforementioned replacing the array with JSON data.

Each row can only be linked into one group, which hopefully simplifies things.

Comment: None of these 3. Read a little about 1NF and 2NF and 3NF and you will get a good direction.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ Thank you for your suggestion. Are you saying I should do the array option and then use 1NF on the array so that I have two columns `link_id` and `row_id` in a third table where `link_id` is not unique?

Answer (score 0):

If each row can be included into multiple linked groups then you can create `LINKS` table with two fields: `ID1`, `ID2` that will store each individual link.

If each row can be only in a single linked group then you can add `GROUP_ID` field to the `positions` table itself.

If the above does not answer your question, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I edited my OP to include clarification: Each row can only be linked into one group. You didn't quite answer the question though, perhaps I didn't ask as clearly as I thought.

Comment: @Tomanow - If each row can belong only to one group of linked rows (let say, students in the same grade, soldiers in the same platoon) then you do not need an additional table from *data modeling* perspective.  You have only two tags [mysql] and [sql] which leads us to believe that your question is about the database and not your application that uses it.

Comment: It would be much simpler if the rows had something in common like your students in the same grade example, unfortunately they will be manually added to a linked group via checkbox. Each linked group needs a unique id so I would want to initially add the data to a separate table with an AI PK. THEN I could use a simple trigger to update each row with the link id if I need to. Read my comment in response to Hanky, I think it is the direction I should be taking. Thank you for your suggestion, I do appreciate the feedback.